# Why does ESP32-LyraT-Mini V1.2 use an external ADC for the microphone when ADC is already available in Audio Codec?

Tags: audio, adc, esp32, microphone, audio-codec

Kindly refer to [ES8311 audio codec datasheet](http://www.everest-semi.com/pdf/ES8311%20PB.pdf) and [ESP32-LyraT-Mini V1.2 Schematic.](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/SCH_ESP32-LyraT-Mini_V1.2_20220119.pdf). In the Lyrat mini board, an external [ADC ES7243](http://www.everest-semi.com/pdf/ES7243%20PB.pdf) is used to sample the audio signal from the microphone but an equally capable ADC is available in the ES8311 codec IC, why does Espressif use the external ADC?
One difference between the ADC in ES8311 codec and ES724 ADC is the former has highest sampling freq of 96khz and the latter 200khz.
[image: System block diagram of Lyrat mini board from the schematic]
 <sup>System block diagram of Lyrat mini board from the schematic</sup>

I am building a project on the basics of this board and I want to know whether I can build my board without the external ADC.